# How to set height and width of an image in html?

Tags: html, css

How to set height and width of an image in html?

[image: FirstImage]

But In My view Image looks like this

[image: secondImage]

Here is html code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgslides">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="uploads/pexels-pixabay-415100.jpg"  />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="uploads/eric-ward-ISg37AI2A-s-unsplash.jpg"  />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="uploads/pexels-helena-lopes-745045.jpg"  />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="uploads/pexels-pixabay-38284.jpg"  />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="uploads/pexels-visionpic-net-341378.jpg"  />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below is the CSS for the html:

**CSS**

```
.sliders
        {
            width:700px;
            height: 400px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .show
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        }
        .imgslides
        {
            width: 500%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
        }
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: have you tried already to use `.slide {object-fit: contain;}`?

Comment: Will try this one bro . Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a height and width for the image if you are uploading it in a size that is bigger than you want to show. Be careful, you have the slide class in the html and in the css it says sliders. You could set the size in the outer div and have the image class be:

```
 .imgclass
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Just remember it is best practice to serve smaller images for smaller screens